# Java nested ConcurrentHashMap is it thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, thread-safety

So this is implementation ..

```
public ConcurrentMap<String , ConcurrentMap<String, Object>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void put(String subKey, String key, Object value) {
    map.putIfAbsent(subKey, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
    map.get(subKey).put(key, value);
}

public Object get(String subKey, String key) {
    return map.get(subKey) == null ? null : map.get(subKey).get(key);
}
```

Put looks thread-safe

- PutIfAbsent is atomic operation.
- Then get inner map and putting value should be thread-safe too, as i think.

Thanks for any clarifications

Comment: This code is *not* thread-safe, trivially `map.get(subKey)` may return a different value on the subsequent executions. While that can be fixed with a temporary variable, it *still might not be atomic enough*: is there a larger required critical region?

Comment: Each individual operation is thread safe, but you have 2 operations on the same map, they aren't thread safe as a pair of operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `put` method, you're always creating a new `ConcurrentHashMap`, even if it is not needed. That is wasteful.

Also, in the `put` method, if a map key can be removed by another thread, the nested map could be removed between the `putIfAbsent` and `get` calls, causing a `NullPointerException`. Use `computeIfAbsent` instead:

```
public void put(String subKey, String key, Object value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(subKey, k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>())
       .put(key, value);
}
```

In the `get` method, you should not call `get` twice, because the value might change between first and second call. Save the value is a variable:

```
public Object get(String subKey, String key) {
    ConcurrentMap<String, Object> subMap = map.get(subKey);
    return subMap == null ? null : subMap.get(key);
}
```

Comment: `map.getOrDefault(subKey, Collections.emptyMap()).get(key)` is neater, I think, for `get`.

Comment: Even with the temporary variable (or getOrDefault) the code may be incorrect due to no extended atomic region. The usage of put wrt. get need to considered in the total program.

Comment: @user2864740 I disagree. If another thread removes the `subKey` or the `key`, the effect will be that the remove either happened before or after this `get(subKey, key)` method call, even if it happens between the two `get()` calls in the method. Even if you synchronized around this, that wouldn't change anything as for the overall *effect*.

Comment: @Sudheera Why do you think that [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) is not thread safe? Did you read the javadoc? *"The entire method invocation is performed **atomically**, so the function is applied at most once per key"*.